# CSS code for user menu navigation background color

Tags: css, colors, menu, background, navigation

I have managed to get the `usermenu` in the navigation bar hover colour to work using this code:

```
.Nav_prim--side .usermenu a.toggle-display:hover{
    background: #0081c6;
}
```

but I can't seem to get the background colour to stay the hover color while the dropdown menu is active, instead it changes to black? How can I get this to work?

[Menu background color after clicking menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcIxz.jpg)

Comment: Please show us a sample of html and the CSS for the dropdown so we can see why this might be happening and be able to help.

Comment: Did :active work?

Comment: Hi Mathew so for the delayed response. I had tried the :active but that didnt work but this did Nav_prim--side .usermenu a.toggle-display:focus

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
a.toggle-display:active{ background: #0081c6; }
```

Let me know if that solves the problem. I'll keep looking :)